# Redis - IIS8 - How to valide the Certificate (Session Cache)

Tags: .net, iis, redis, stackexchange.redis

Good morning all,

I need to replace AppFabric for Redis in an app park with many components and multiple web pages.
And my job is to make this change with the **least possible impact** on applications code.

**I use**

- Redis 6 (in a cluster of 3 servers with an NLB in front);
- Framework 4.8;
- StackExchange.Redis 2.2.4 or +;
- Connection with certificate validation;
- I'm not on Azure;

**FOR Server Cache**

- The server cache is operated with a common component, the encapsulation here makes it easy to reduce the impact;
- The following code work perfectly to replace AppFabric for the connection;

```
////Connection... SSL REDIS6
ConfigurationOptions options = new ConfigurationOptions()
{
   EndPoints = { { "MyNLB", 6379 } },
   Ssl = true,
   SslProtocols = SslProtocols.Tls12,
   Password = "MyPassword"
};
options.CertificateValidation += CheckServerCertificate; // <--- here it is the delegate who verifies the certificate ...

using (ConnectionMultiplexer redisConn = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(options))
{
   // <<<<< CONNECTED >>>>>
   IDatabase db = redisConn.GetDatabase();

   //My commands GET / SET / ETC..
}
// <<<<< DISCONNECTED >>>>>
```

**FOR Session Cache**

I use

- IIS8;

In the Web.Config file

```
<add name="MySessionStateStore" 
               type="Microsoft.Web.Redis.RedisSessionStateProvider" 
               host="MyNLB" 
               port="6379" 
               accessKey="MyPassword" 
               ssl="true" 
               protocol="tls12" />
```

- Here I have a problem, I don't know how to perform my certificate validation. Should I use the IIS Initialize to create my connection with certificate validation?
  - Be careful, I don't want to change the code of the web pages.
- How do I do that? Is it possible?

Thanks,

Frankie

Comment: You can take a look at: https://www.thesslstore.com/knowledgebase/ssl-install/microsoft-iis-7-ssl-installation/

Comment: Applying Theobald's recommendations I got the following error:
Endpoint 127.0.0.0:7000 serving hashslot 4284 is not reachable at this point of time. Please check connectTimeout value. etc...

This error occurs at the level of the server cache when there is no validation of the certificate (delegate)

Any ideas? Thank you

Comment: Whether your application is properly deployed on IIS, you can redeploy your application and then configure certificate verification for it.